# Unruly CSS Pseudo Element Box Shadow

Tags: html, css

I am working on a new layout for a website, and I am extremely close to achieving the result I want. However, there is one problem. I am using an adaptation of the technique described here (http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/demo/backgrounds.html, see the 3 column example just below the gorillas). Basically, my version uses an absolutely positioned CSS pseudo element as the backgrounds for the left column.

My problem arises when I attempt to apply a `box-shadow` to the pseudo element. The element, and its shadow, always appear on top of my main column.

To make all of this clearer I have created a simple example page here: http://www.3strandsmarketing.com/test4.html

My fear is that since I'm using a pseudo element based on the parent of my main column, it will never be able to sit under it, but I'm hoping there's some way this can be worked around. Any ideas?

Comment: Haha, well I feel like an idiot. The z-index was working properly. It only looked wrong because I was using semi-transparent rgba colors for the backgrounds. Sorry to have wasted anyone's time.

Comment: Hadn't thought / seen this method fpr making a 'faux' column before, neat.

Comment: Yeah, Nicholas Gallagher is a genius. Just in case anyone is wondering, the rest of the layout (apart from the faux column) is adapted from http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/

Comment: If you have found an answer to your own question, please post it as an answer so that others may learn, and then mark it as accepted if it is the correct answer.

Comment: @cdeszaq, I can definitely do that. I just thought the nature of the problem didn't warrant it as there really was no problem. Should I post the answer, or simply delete the question?

Comment: @DominicP - Whichever you feel more comfortable with. Leaving the question and providing what you found as an answer is probably the best, since others found this question interesting enough to up-vote it 4 times. And who knows, it might help someone else down the road.

Comment: I am interested in a working solution/example, if it's not too much to ask for :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution here is to not use semi-transparent (rgba) colors for the main column. Otherwise, you will be able to see the drop shadow of the sidebar column through it, ruining the effect of one being on top of the other.

To see the correct effect, visit the example page, and use Firebug or another DOM manipulating tool to change the background color for the `#main-content` div from `rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.2)` to `rgba(0, 100, 0, 1)`. You should now see that it is indeed "on top" of the left side bar.